# Too long to power up

Tags: wingpanel, plank, startup, cpu, asus

I guess this may be a repost, but I'm using a very good pc(i7-4720HQ, 8gb ram, gtx 950m 4gb) and after I enter my password is taking like 1-2 min for dock and wingpanel to show up. Does anyone know why is this taking so much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with DBus - see the answer I posted [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10272/5722).

Essentially DBus is preventing everything from starting up, so until that's fixed you need to rename the file causing issues:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

Comment: one more question, does it works if i'm in dual boot with win 8.1?

Comment: Yes, this shouldn't affect that.