# Desktop takes forever to load after restart

Tags: release-loki, wingpanel, plank

When I restart my OS, I log in.  The desktop does not load for a full 2 minutes after typing my password. I can move my mouse and see my desktop background.  No apps. Happens pretty much every time I reboot.  I have a 2017 Dell XPS.  Performance is excellent other than this odd issue.

How do I figure out what is causing this?  How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm facing the same problems.
The login bug was already addressed to the development team: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377

Comment: Ash, thank you, I hadn't seen this. I'm glad that the bug has been brought to their attention. Apart from a few other minor things, I am loving this new env though!

Comment: I have the same issue as you, after loading to my login screen it takes a lot of time to load the dock and the panel, quite confusing, still unable to locate the issue.Anyone?

Comment: who can help me

Comment: Can confirm that running `sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled` fixed the issue on both of my devices. Thanks I read and find this way to fix it ,but I'm not sure, I haven't try it.when I tried I will report it

Comment: If the answer below resolved the issue for you, you should accept the answer.

Comment: Confirmed. Have eOS installed on 3 different computers. Happens on all them. It seems to happen more often after updates to the kernel, but will happen at random. What I see: - Update the kernel / system files
- Reboot
- Login
- Get wallpaper and mouse cursor only for 4-5 minutes
- Desktop finally loads

Comment: Same problem as here (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/13881/long-boot-time-after-recent-updates#comment16864_13881) and here (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/infinite-loop-on-login-screen)

Comment: I made a fresh Loki installation and I'm having this issue. Now I used the tip from David above and let's see what happens.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the "solution": > sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.disable is not helping at all. What else could it be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A solution (or at least temporary workaround) proposed in the bug discussion
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377 - is to rename the file:

/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop

to

/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled

This fixed it immediately for me.

Comment: thanks, that worked for me too bro!!! right now after login just take 2-10 seconds :))

Comment: This also resolved the problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Didn't worked for me

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in dbus. There is an upstream fix but unfortunately it hasn't made its way into elementary yet ([apparently the fix is in staging, so it should appear soon](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/5nt48i/anyone_experiencing_slingshot_issues_during/dcekabd/)).

> I think the related problem is explained and fixed here:
>   https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-July/msg02793.html
>
> OS Loki is running dbus-daemon 1.10.6 from 2015-12-1 while the problem was fixed in July 2016. An update to newer dbus version (one after 1.10.10) should fix the issue.
>
> To fix the issue for now:
>   Rename the file to at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop

https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377/comments/27

If you don't want to mess about with files I've found the following temporary workaround:

1. Enter a PTTY (Press `CTRL` `+` `ALT` `+` `F1`.
2. Login.
3. Restart lightdm with `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`.
4. You will be taken back to the login screen, login and Slingshot should appear instantly this time.

Comment: Thanks a lot I read it and find. Something I will try it

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered once you find your solution!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it can be Fixed I haven't tried it. When I Fixed it . I will be change it

Comment: When I do this command, my screen goes black and I only see my mouse in the middle of my screen.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here, to temporarily avoid that wait of 5 minutes:

1. press `alt+f1`
2. enter your username/password
3. restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: While this reduces the wait time until you can try again in the login screen, it haven't solved the recurring issue (at least for me)

Answer (score 2):

A solution (or at least temporary workaround) proposed in the bug [discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377) - is to rename the file:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop
```

to

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.disabled
```

Yes. this happened to me as well.

Comment: I wait more than 30 min. But no result

Comment: can you try the above?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377).  Apparently this issue also [applies](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1599110/comments/17) to Ubuntu. There is an assistive app in the autostart that runs terribly slow. I went to the startup directory:

`cd /etc/xdg/autostart/`

I changed the file extension for the problem file to effectively prevent it from starting

`sudo mv at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop_DISABLED`

Now my machine boots in ~5 seconds vs 120 seconds.

[AT SPI D-Bus Bus](https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/manage-the-startup-applications/)

```
AT SPI stands for Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface, a framework to integrate accessibility functions in applications. This command will create a new DBus for AT SPI specific functions.
Command: /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher –-launch-immediately
Status: unwanted until you need the accessibility features.
Reference: https://www.linuxfoundation.org/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in dbus.

Workaround:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop.backup
```

More info:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1596377 or https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2016-July/msg02793.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Razer Blade Stealth from late 2016 with integrated Intel graphics. I'm having this problem on a fresh install (dual-boot with Windows) and no solution seems to be helping. I renamed that file which seems to fix the problem for everyone else, I restarted lightdm, I installed drivers and updates, and I reinstalled the operating system more times than I can count.
Is there anything else I can do to fix this? The default desktop background is a beautiful tree, but I'd love it if I could use eOS as an operating system instead of just a nice digital picture frame.
Thank you!