# Long boot after sing in

Tags: boot, greeter

I enter password. It's ok.
I see empty desktop with only background picture.
I wait for about 1-2 minutes and only after it the dock line and high line with time and applications become visible and available.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This is a duplicate question of https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12155/desktop-takes-forever-to-load-after-restart, the problem is related to a known dbus error where the fix hasn't made its way into Elementary yet.