# Graphics and login problems on late 2016 Razer Blade Stealth

Tags: release-loki

I'm having a couple of problems with a clean install of Loki on my late 2016 model Razer Blade Stealth with an Intel i7-7500U (Kaby Lake) CPU and integrated graphics.

I'm able to boot to the login screen, but if I go to the command line (`CTRL`+`ALT`+`F1`) the screen starts flickering. If I try to login, the screen fills with static and doesn't show the desktop, regardless of how long I wait.
If I boot into recovery mode, the flickering goes away and the static is reduced, but when I try to login, it shows the cursor and the desktop background and becomes unresponsive.

Here's what I've tried thus far:

- Clean installing the OS, God knows how many times
- The good ol' `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, thinking it was a driver problem
- I tried installing `xserver-org-video-intel` and its dependencies
- I renamed the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop` as described [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10120/14795)
- I added `nomodeset` to the Grub configuration as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/38782)
- I `sudo apt-get install`ed `intel-microcode`, which turns out was already installed

If there's any way to get Elementary to work on this laptop, some instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!