# eOS freezes after installation

Tags: release-juno, boot

I recently installed elementary os alongside with windows 10. After installing it with usb, it boots and lock screen pops up but after i enter my password pantheon doesnt start and it freezes with only showing wallpaper.
what should i do?
edit: some back info
i upgraded my ssd it was m.2 sata now it is nvme. i installed windows 10 first then elementary. it automatically boots into elementary os right now. my laptop has 2 graphic cards intel and nvidia. i tried apt-get purge nvidia but it doesn’t have nvidia drivers. i tried deleting then downloading pantheon but i couldn’t download after deleting it.i reinstalled eOS after doing this. also i turn ahci mode on on bios.

Comment: See if this helps? -> https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12155/desktop-takes-forever-to-load-after-restart

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a text console by pressing ctrl+alt+F1 then login and do full upgrades with apt update, apt upgrade and apt dist-upgrade.

Then reboot and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the same problem few times and I do not know a universal solution, because probably it has different reasons to occure.

1/ I recommend you to try the solution on [Desktop takes forever to load after restart](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12155/desktop-takes-forever-to-load-after-restart)

2/ If it does not help,go into console login by pressing ctr+alt+F1 and after login there type `sudo service lightdm restart` and probably you will be redirected again to the login screen of the pantheon-greeter. If it does not happen but errors occured, then type into console `reboot` and usually after the reboot (or login again through graphical login interface of the greeter) the problem is resolved.

3/ I do this when the above does not help - it is to reinstall the nvidia drivers. I use the proprietary ones from https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa . You can add them by executing into console login (ctrl+alt+f1) the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
 sudo apt update 
 sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Good luck!